# angular Accessing ngModel controller in directive with custom template in compile

Tags: angularjs, directive

I want to access the ngModel controller (to later use setValidity to validate the custom input field). However, when I want to use the directive as an attribute (not class), the replaceWith function throws an error that It can not find ngModel controller. I created a fiddle here:

jsfiddle.net/6HcGS/396

Can anybody help me out?

This is related to my first questions:

[databinding custom directive angular with replacing html in compile function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597068/databinding-custom-directive-angular-with-replacing-html-in-compile-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input zippy ng-model="title">
```

zippy and ngModel are both directives that are render in a specific order. In this case zippy gets rendered before ngModel. You can reorder the directives like Maxim Shoustin suggested or you could specify the rendering order by providing a `priority` attribute on the directive creation function like so:

```
  .directive('zippy', function($compile){
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      priority: -1,
      replace: true,
      ...
```

The default preority is 0. Directives with higher priorities are rendered first.

Comment: yes, I thought about to set priority, it should work as well. In my projects I try to write custom directives in 1st place. Anyways +1 :)

Comment: Thnx a bunch! I would never think about prioritizing directives to make this work!

Answer (score 1):

Instead

```
<input zippy ng-model="title"/>
```

try to write attribute after `ng-model` like:

```
 <input  ng-model="title" zippy/>
```

You interesting to load `zippy` before `ng-model` directive.

Like bekite says, set `priority: -1`

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6HcGS/416/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! Great answer to my question!